# Codeigniter db->update() VS MySQL native UPDATE Affected rows: 0

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, rows-affected

Using MySQL alone - If I make a basic update to a table like this:

```
UPDATE `SOMETABLE` SET `NAME` = 'John' WHERE `ID` = 1;
```

And the value of `NAME` = '**John**' was already '**John**' - in other-words - nothing is new, nothing to update. MySQL returns "**Affected rows: 0 (Query took 0.0007 sec)**"

If I make the same call - now using CodeIgniter - and then retrieve the affected rows like this:

```
$data = array(
               'NAME' => 'John'
            );

$this->db->where('ID', 1);
$this->db->update('SOMETABLE', $data); 
$affect = $this->db->affected_rows();

echo $affect; // $affect echos 1
```

---

**$affect** ends up equaling 1.
I haven't got a problem with this - I just expected that if there was nothing to update - that codeigniter would behave the same way as MySQL and not edit something that does not need to be updated, and return 0 for affected_rows().

- Have I got this wrong some way?
- Is codeigniter overwriting '**John**'? or not?

Comment: Just curiosity here: why are you passing the ID as a string?

Comment: Based on your findings, I wonder what the load is (I realize nil on such a basic query). Obviously MySQL is hitting the db and basically doing a select to see if an update is needed and then an update if needed. Whereas CI just makes the update. I'm assuming that a select is quicker/less resource intensive than an update. Good question. 1-up

Comment: My Bad - This suggestion here by @Dwight with $this->db->last_query(); caused me to find my error. I had a time stamp date(DATE_RFC822) added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the query that CodeIgniter is running using the following code:

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

Also post the query you are using to interact with MySQL, just to confirm that the exact same query is being run.

CodeIgniter does have a hack for MySQL that adjusts the reporting of affected rows, however I was under the impression it was only for DELETE queries. If you look at `system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php` or `system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php` (whichever driver you are using and look at the variable `var $delete_hack = TRUE;`. Adjusting that might impact your result, could be worth a try?

Comment: Codeigniter's function is only:

    function affected_rows()
    {
       return @mysql_affected_rows($this->conn_id);
    }

So I believe it is your query

Comment: My Bad - This suggestion here by @Dwight with $this->db->last_query(); caused me to find my error. I had a time stamp date(DATE_RFC822) added in the middle of the call there and I overlooked it... My bad.. I feel embarrassed now :( - But really glad that you guys helped... What do we do about this question now? I don;t want to confuse anyone with this.