# How to update database column value with CONCAT() function using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Write now i'm using this query -

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE my_table SET member = CONCAT(member,',',$user_id) WHERE id=$id");
```

How I convert this query in Codeigniter style, like `$this->db->update(...)`

Comment: $this->db->set('member ', 'CONCAT(member,',',$user_id)', FALSE);

Comment: This question shows a comparison and might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14720854/367456

Comment: Double quotes can be used so variable interpolation will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this but not tested

```
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$this->db->set('member', 'CONCAT(member,\',\',\''.$user_id.'\')', FALSE);
$this->db->update('my_table');
```